# Backbone weird TypeError error on .bind('all', 'update')?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want my `ApplicationView` to listen all events on the router. It works if i do:

```js
this.model.router.on('route:myroute1, 'update');
this.model.router.on('route:myroute2, 'update');
this.model.router.on('route:myroute3, 'update');
```

When i try to bind `all` event:

```js
this.model.router.bind('all', 'update');
```

I got this horrible error:

> TypeError: all[i].apply is not a function
>
> all[i].apply(all[i + 1] || this, args);

The view (define as a requirejs module):

```js
define(['backbone', 'lodash'], function(Backbone, _) {

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        el: 'body',

        initialize: function() {
            this.model.router.bind('all', 'update');

            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'update');
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() { },

        update: function(route) {
            this.$el
                .find('.nav-collapse a[href=#'+ route +']')
                .parent()
                    .addClass('active')
                    .siblings()
                        .removeClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

While this is where error happens in the original source code:

```js
 // Execute "all" callbacks.
if (all) {
    args = [event].concat(rest);
    for (i = 0, length = all.length; i < length; i += 2) {
        all[i].apply(all[i + 1] || this, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `on()` / `bind()` is supposed to be a function. Is that an undocumented feature that you can pass a string instead? What object does it call that method on in that case? Are you sure it works in your first case?

What happens if you do this instead?:

```
this.model.router.bind('all', this.update);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at the Backbone source and it doesn't look like it would support passing a string as the second argument. Also, it looks like you're going to want to register the event listener like this, with the context argument: `this.model.router.on( 'all', this.update, this );`

Comment: `this.model.router.bind('all', this.update);` is wrong, as it will immediately call that function...

Comment: No, it won't. It's passing the function object, `this.update`, to `bind()`. This would call the function immediately: `this.model.router.bind( 'all', this.update() );`

Comment: Yep, but i need to pass the current route. Anywal i solved thanks to your help :)) `this.model.router.on('all', function(route) { this.update(route); }, this);`

Comment: That's unnecessary, just call `this.model.router.on('all', this.update, this);`. Right now you're just wrapping it in an additional function call that doesn't accomplish anything.